# I'm working on a game using tkinter. Go a stupid error

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, typeerror, python-3.7, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *
import random
import time

tk = Tk()
tk.title("Game")
tk.resizable(0, 0)
tk.wm_attributes("-topmost", 1)
canvas = Canvas(tk, width=500, height=400, bd=0, highlightthickness=0)
canvas.pack()
tk.update()

class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()

    def hit_paddle(self, pos):
        paddle_pos = self.canvas.coords(self.paddle.id)
        if pos[2] >= paddle_pos[0] and pos[0] <= paddle_pos[2]:
            if pos[3] >= paddle_pos[1] and pos[3] <= paddle_pos[3]:
                return True
            return False
    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, self.y)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.y = 3
        if pos[3] >= self.canvas_height:
            self.y = -3
        if self.hit_paddle(pos) == True:
            self.y = -3
        if pos[0] <= 0:
            self.x = 3
        if pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = -3

class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)

    def draw(self):
        self.canvas.move(self.id, self.x, 0)
        pos = self.canvas.coords(self.id)
        if pos[1] <= 0:
            self.x = 0
        elif pos[2] >= self.canvas_width:
            self.x = 0

    def turn_left(self, evt):
        self.x = -2

    def turn_right(self, evt):
        self.x = +2

paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue') - line 70 is here
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red') 

while 1:
    ball.draw()
    paddle.draw()
    tk.update_idletasks()
    tk.update()
    time.sleep(0.015)
```

I get an error that looks like this:

> line 70, in  paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue') TypeError:
>   **init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'color'

I tried to fix my Paddle class code but it looks fine for me. 
Even though I have a color argument in there it still gives me an error

Comment: `def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):` Your Paddle class requires 3 arguments.

Comment: But after that i get another error:

Comment: File "C:\Users\\Documents\What I made with Python\Working on\MyBookGame.py", line 48, in __init__
    self.paddle = paddle
NameError: name 'paddle' is not defined

Comment: It seems like the `paddle` argument is unnecessary, just take it out of the constructor.

Comment: Yeah but after I delete it it will still ask me to call it. So I get an error:line 70, in <module>
    ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')
TypeError: __init__() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: Sorry, i'm a student. So i'm dumb

Comment: Teachers can't explain it as well as they should

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mixed up the constructors for `Ball` and `Paddle`. It should be like this.

```
class Ball:
    def __init__(self, canvas, paddle, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.paddle = paddle
        self.id = canvas.create_oval(10, 10, 25, 25, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 245, 100)
        starts = [-3, -2, -1, 1, 2, 3]
        random.shuffle(starts)
        self.x = starts[0]
        self.y = -3
        self.canvas_height = self.canvas.winfo_height()
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
```

And

```
class Paddle:
    def __init__(self, canvas, color):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self.id = canvas.create_rectangle(0, 0, 100, 10, fill=color)
        self.canvas.move(self.id, 200, 300)
        self.x = 0
        self.canvas_width = self.canvas.winfo_width()
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Left>', self.turn_left)
        self.canvas.bind_all('<KeyPress-Right>', self.turn_right)
```

And now this will work

```
paddle = Paddle(canvas, 'blue')
ball = Ball(canvas, paddle, 'red')
```

Comment: Thanks dude. No, really, you wasted your time just so you can help me. BIG BIG BIG  THANKS TO YOU